# Open cmd with Python Os.system and run commands inside the new opened cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cmd, python-os

I need to click in a button to call a python function (i did this), but now :
I need a python script to open a new cmd, and in the opened cmd i want to do 2 commands :
Cd and run a python file
This code is the best thing i could do but it's not running the script !

```
import os
    username = os.getlogin()
    os.system('start cmd /k ; cd C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\Desktop\\Automatisation & python serverSender.py')
```

To resume :
Start cmd /k (Open new cmd and remain)
cd C:\Users\' + username + '\Desktop\Automatisation (To change directory)
python serverSender.py (To run the python script inside Automatisation directory)

But the last command : python serverSender.py is not executing ! As you can see in the screen, the function opens a new cmd when i click on the button , it's goes to the directory in the cd command, but it's not starting the serverSender.py file !
[Cmd Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcwU4.png)

Any idea on how to run the third command ? (i don't want to run it in another cmd, i want to run it in the opened cmd with the first command )
Thanks !

Comment: Technically the `CD` and `python.exe` commands are a single argument attributed to the `/K` option. i.e. `cmd /K "YourCommand(s)"`, _(note the correct double quoting of the single argument)_. Example ```cmd.exe /K "CD /D "%UserProfile:\=\\%\\Desktop\\Automatisation" && python.exe "serverSender.py""``` I will say however that none of that is required, because you could just use `os.chdir()` to run `cmd.exe`, or more simply, `python.exe`, with a particular working directory, instead of changing it after launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` is interpreted by the outer shell and not the one inside `start`. You need to escape it, by changing `&` to `^&`:

```py
os.system('start cmd /k ; cd C:\\Users\\' + username + '\\Desktop\\Automatisation ^& python serverSender.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

Having tried to check into this, I don't think it is a python issue.

I tried doing this, from a command line, for comparison:

start cmd /k cd .. & cd ..

It did not work. Only the first "cd .." got executed.

So it seems "&" is not a successful way to chain commands with "cmd /k". I checked && and that did not work either.

After further looking into it, there is one suggested workaround I found at the below link, which involves using a single line to temporarily write a script and execute that script. (though I did not try it)

https://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline

Comment: The comment above of CherryDT Worked ! Thanks !